# the difference of String.valueOf(char)  and +

Tags: java, string, char, default-value

to show the default value of char ,I wrote code like this:

```
public class TestChar {
  static char a;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("."+String.valueOf(a)+".");
    System.out.println("the default char is "+a);
  }   
}
```

but the console output is confused.the first is ". ." ,however the second is "the default char is [](like this  ,I don't know how to describe it.)" why?thanks for help

Comment: No, I am not seeing square brackets [] as output. It just empty.

Comment: to Nambari:but my output is square ...sure

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: To get the value of the char try to cast it into an int. System.out.println("."+ (int)a +"."); As the others said the value will be 0 (try with char a = 'A' and you will get 65 for example)

Comment: I am using Netbeans and it is printing empty. May be something related to eclipse? Could you run from command prompt and see?

Comment: It's gonna depend on the font. You are trying to print \0, or NUL, which isn't a part of most fonts. On windows, it prints this character:

Comment: To Nambari:It's empty when run from command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user1681360 mentioned, it is the character `'\0'` you are printing. You have not initialized your field, so Java initializes it for you to the default value, unprintable character `'\0'`. Depending on the environment, unprintable characters will be shown as empty boxes, question marks, etc.

In the first line you are first creating a `String`, then appending it. In the second line the operator `String + char` is compiled to `java.lang.StringBuilder#append(char)`, so you are directly appending a character to the buffer, rather that creating a temporary `String`.

Indeed the two approaches are always equivalent, even when the character in question is `'\0'`. The character `'\0'` has a special treatment in Java Language Specification, but that does not affect this particular behavior.

Answer (score 2):

A char is not a String. In your first print statement you are converting the char to a string and then printing the value. In the second line you're just printing the value of the char directly.

Comment: but the + will convert char to String.isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the value of a, so it is equivalent to char a = 0; a non-printable character.

Initialize the value to something lets say static char a = 'a'; That should show you something.

Update: as the second character is non-printable it is displayed as a square but it is in fact a '\0' character.

Update 2: The default value is 0, as in the number 0, not the character '0'.

Comment: The question is about the default value of a char.